# python replace line text with weired characters

Tags: regex, python-3.x, line, str-replace

How do I replace the following using python

```
GSA*HC*11177*NYSfH-EfC*23130303*0313*1*R*033330103298
STEM*333*3001*0030303238
BHAT*3319*33*33377*23330706*031829*RTRCP
NUM4*41*2*My Break Room Place*****6*1133337
```

I want to replace the all character after first occurence of '*' . All characters must be replace except '*'

Example input:

```
NUM4*41*2*My Break Room Place*****6*1133337
```

example output:

```
NUM4*11*1*11 11111 1111 11111*****1*1111111
```

Comment: Please provide the code that is not working for you.

Comment: I am not sure how to proceed. I am able to read the file line by line, but don't know what to do after that.
        for read1 in open_reading_input_file:
            line_counter += 1
            read1 = read1.replace('~\n', '')
            read1.find('*')

Comment: See http://ideone.com/tTdITd

Comment: It is working good but all the data is comming in one line when I do f.write. How do i insert new line after every line write part ?

Comment: output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

Comment: Do you mean the text above is read in as a single string? Split with `\n` and then join back after processing.

Comment: Also the 'My Break Room Place' is misssing the blank spaces. it is discarding blankspaces. I need the space part to be as it is. space should not be repalced with any thing else

Comment: Does it mean all chars except `*` **and space** should be replaced with `1`? Are there any more requirements you forgot to tell us?

Comment: Thats about it. Sorry I missed it. Yes except * and space should be replaced with 1 and each line should be in new line. Not just one single line.

Comment: Try replace [`^([^*]*\*)|[^\s*]` with `$11`](https://regex101.com/r/Clf4RH/1)

Comment: See http://ideone.com/6LSoXJ

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much.

Comment: You may also use sln's solution. I have the last modification of my approach to account for all whitespace  - http://ideone.com/ZpHOIA

Comment: @bobblebubble Your solution is the best, but the replacement is `r'\g<1>1'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks could not test and how about `${1}1` ?

Comment: @bobblebubble - By doing a blind replacement you end up adding an extra `1` after capture group 1. `NUM4*` => `NUM4*1`

Comment: @sln well spotted! already appraised your solution.

Comment: @bobblebubble: Well, sln is right. Besides, it will only work in Python 3.5+, not in older versions.

Answer (score 2):

Fairly simple, use a callback to return group 1 (if matched) unaltered, otherwise
return replacement `1`

*Note - this also would work in multi-line strings.

If you need that, just add `(?m)` to the beginning of the regex. `(?m)(?:(^[^*]*\*)|[^*\s])`*

You'd probably want to test the string for the `*` character first.

```
    ( ^ [^*]* \* )           # (1), BOS/BOL up to first *
 |                         # or,
    [^*\s]                   # Not a * nor whitespace
```

Python

```
import re

def repl(m):
    if ( m.group(1) ) : return m.group(1)
    return "1"

str = 'NUM4*41*2*My Break Room Place*****6*1133337'

if ( str.find('*') ) :
    newstr = re.sub(r'(^[^*]*\*)|[^*\s]', repl, str)
    print newstr
else :
    print '* not found in string'
```

Output

```
NUM4*11*1*11 11111 1111 11111*****1*1111111
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use regex, you can use this one: `(?<=\*)[^\*]+` with [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.sub)

```
inputs = ['GSA*HC*11177*NYSfH-EfC*23130303*0313*1*R*033330103298',
'STEM*333*3001*0030303238',
'BHAT*3319*33*33377*23330706*031829*RTRCP',
'NUM4*41*2*My Break Room Place*****6*1133337']
outputs = [re.sub(r'(?<=\*)[^\*]+', '1', inputline) for inputline in inputs]
```

Regex explication [here](https://regex101.com/r/IldUzz/1)